# Computing cost for crypto futures trades

Tags: futures, margin, initial-margin

I'm trying to replicate the cost of cryptofutures trade without success. Here are the inputs and the cost i got:

Quantity: 1 BTC

Mark Price: 11732.72 USD

Leverage:20

Margin Percentage: 2.5%

THE COST: 4760.46 USD

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? there are fees you pay when you open the position(depends market orders or limit orders), funding fees which get change every 8 hours and closing position fees.

Comment: Cost cannot be 4k at trade initiation probably market has moved or by cost you are commenting initial margin? Can you put a screenshot from the exchange for this trade